# Can I change the text color of a JQuery validator method?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors

I'm trying to create a validation for file extension and size with JQuery but the text that appears is white with a white background.

I tried with CSS but nothing happens

Is it any way to change it directly on Jquery?

```
    <script>

    $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
    }, 'Wrong size');
    $.validator.addMethod('extension', function (value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
    }, 'Wrong extension');
    jQuery(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $('#form').validate({
            rules: {
                file: {
                    required: false,
                    extension: "ai,pdf,zip,rar,jpeg,jpg,png",
                    filesize: 8388600,
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter `errorClass`

```
$('#form').validate({
  errorClass: "your-custom-classname", 
  rules: { 
    file: { 
      required: false, 
      extension: "ai,pdf,zip,rar,jpeg,jpg,png",
      filesize: 8388600
    } 
  },
 });
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: I did it but now the message doesn't even appears

Comment: Done, thanks a lot there was a missing coma after de classname

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this code

$('#myForm').validate({
   errorClass:'myClass'
   //your options
});

Comment: Now the message doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Validator append `<span class="error">Field error rule message</span>` to the input fields.

You can add custom attributes to the `error` class if you want.

```
.error{
     color : red; // for danger text color
}
```